# A graph G which can’t be painted properly in 2000 colors

Tags: graph-theory

A graph G which can’t be painted properly in 2000 colors (i.e. any two adjacent
vertices have different colors) is given. The graph is properly painted in 2016
colors. Prove that a path of length 2000 through vertices of different colors can be
found

Comment: Is the graph connected? Without further restrictions the statement is incorrect to my knowledge: For instance, a graph with 2016 vertices but no edges can be properly colored in 2016 different colors, but there is no path of length 2000.

Comment: its connected...

Answer (score 1):

First, let me generalize the statement a bit:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph with chromatic number $\chi(G)\in\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. the smallest number of colors needed for a proper coloring of $G$). Then there exists a path of length $\chi(G)-1$ through vertices of different colors.

Note that the existence of a path of length $\chi(G)-1$ also yields the existence of a path of length $k$ for any $k \in \{1,\dots,\chi(G)-2\}$, so that your statement follows.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with chromatic number $\chi(G) \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $f \colon V \to \{1,\dots,\chi(G)\}$ be a (surjective) coloring of $G$. According to the Gallai-Hasse-Roy-Vitaver theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Hasse%E2%80%93Roy%E2%80%93Vitaver_theorem)), every *orientation* of $G$ (which can be seen as a function assigning each edge $\{u,v\} \in E$ a directed edge $(u,v)$ or $(v,u)$, turning $G$ into a digraph) contains a simple directed path with $\chi(G)$ vertices (i.e. of length $\chi(G)-1$). We define an orientation $g$ on $G$ by setting $g(\{u,v\}):= (u,v)$ if $f(u) < f(v)$ and $g(\{u,v\})=(v,u)$ if $f(u) > f(v)$ for every $\{u,v\} \in E$. Now in the obtained digraph, any directed path goes through vertices with increasing values of $f$ and the theorem yields the existence of a directed path of length $\chi(G)-1$. If we remove the orientation again, this directed path becomes an undirected path in $G$ of length $\chi(G)-1$ going through vertices of different colors, which proves the statement.

Note that the quoted theorem also contains some "maximality" statement, and it is clear that this maximality transfers to our problem: There is no path of length greater than $\chi(G)-1$ going through vertices of different color.

Comment: I have tried to prove the statement by induction in several ways, but always got stuck at the inductive step. After some googling, I found the Gallai-Hasse-Roy-Vitaver theorem which gives a nice duality between the chromatic number of a graph and paths in its oriented digraphs and which is immensely helpful for this problem. Still it would be nice to see a more direct proof, perhaps by induction (but maybe such a proof would require similar effort as the proof of the Gallai-Hasse-Roy-Vitaver theorem (?)).